# What are the Geometric Properties of Non Integer Vector Spaces?

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces, fractals

I found a paper from Princeton called ["Axiomatic Basis for Spaces with Non Integer Dimension"](https://www.princeton.edu/~fhs/paper91/paper91.pdf) that presents five axioms and then starts to create a framework similar to what I'd think the subject would look like. However, a lot of questions are left unanswered.

I think this is more of a mathematical question than a physical question simply because the math isn't very well developed if at all, thus an physical questions regarding my question are irrelevant since there's nothing, at least currently, to study.

Is this a subject with a searchable name? If so, what are some good papers to read? (No paywalls please) Also, feel free to provide intuition for any, or all, of this :)

Comment: Did you check whether that paper cited or was cited by other related ones?

Comment: @Clement C. There a a paper by Wilson he cited...but it's title is "field theory in less than four dimensions"...and its behind a pay wall.

Comment: This one? http://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C720906/papers/v2p169.pdf

Comment: @Clement C. Well that's odd...that paper doesn't seem related at all. I used the reference as given by (24) K.G. Wilson, Phys. Rev. D 7, 2911 (1973).

Comment: You may also want to look at [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22Axiomatic+Basis+for+Spaces+with+Non+Integer+Dimension%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=), and click on the "Cited by" link...